# learning the Kora

Tags: sheet-music, instruments, ethnomusicology, african

Are there any written methods for learning the Kora,  a West African instrument which traditionally is taught only by example and whose repertoire is not notated?

Comment: Best I've found so far, but you really, really want to be able to read German, as the English (and other) translations are sporadic: http://www.kora-music.com/.

Comment: Just a thought - you **might** be able to find and adapt things for the Gravikord, an electric instrument based on the kora. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravikord

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response guys snd thanks for the comments.  the Kora website is good,  but their way of notating Kora music seems clumsy and difficult to read.. maybe I'll try devising a new method or adapting two staves of regular notation (one for each hand).

Answer (score 1):

Resources:

1.) http://www.kora-music.com/e/notationssystem.htm

2.) http://www.derekgripper.com/african-guitar/reading-kora-scores/

3.) A [34 page pdf](http://digitalcollections.sit.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1835&context=isp_collection) by William Ridenour

4.) For purchase, [a book](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30249953) by Roderic Knight

5.) [Several places to purchase African Music Scores](http://www.africanmusic.org/sources.html)

6.) http://www.oscarvandillen.com/kora-music/

Also, [Sona Jobarteh](http://www.sonajobarteh.com/) is a composer and Kora virtuoso - she has workshops but, the site doesn't explicitly state written resources are provided....

A quick image search for 'kora sheet music' pulls up a lot of material - I did not examine them closely for duplicates, etc...